# How to write formula in Saleforce for checkbox

Tags: formula

I am quite new to formula.
How can we write formula for - I want a checkbox to be set as True if Price value(Number) is more than 30.

Comment: Welcome to SFSE! We're a community building a public knowledge base around solving specific problems. We always look for questions to contain an attempt at solving a problem - have you tried something and gotten stuck? You can [edit] to add information.

Comment: If you're new to a piece of functionality, the best place to start is Trailhead, which has [modules](https://trailhead.salesforce.com/en/content/learn/modules/point_click_business_logic) covering formulas.

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned in the comments, you'll definitely want to use Trailhead to get a general overview of formulas.  In this case, it's the IF function that will do the trick:

```
IF(PriceField > 30, true, false)
```

Edit: as pointed out in the comments, the IF/True/False part isn't strictly necessary.  You may omit them if you become comfortable with formulas and don't have junior team members who need things explicitly spelled out.

Comment: Or just PriceField > 30 and let the system decide if that's a true or false statement. The "IF" function is redundant.